# scroll view can't scroll either bottom or top while edit text soft keyboard is open

Tags: android

In my layout i have some edit text and a scroll view.The problem is when I touch the edit text the soft keyboard is open but if i try to scroll down it is not scrolling down fully. Same case happen when i try to scroll up fully.

But if i use   android : windowSoftInputMode="adjustresize" i can scroll fully up but my keyboard hide the bottom edit text.I also try to use 
android : windowSoftInputMode="adjustspan|adjustresize" but no solution found.

Another problem is that I show some error message when user try to input same text if it is match but when close the soft keyboard the message is not attaching with its right position.

its my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolabar"
        android:theme="@style/mycustomtoolbartheme"></include>
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_addproductactivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_add_product"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
           >



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_save_addProductActivity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape1"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_view_addProductActivity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape1"
                    android:text="view"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">



                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autocomplitePn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Product Name"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autocompliteBn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Brand Name"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_MN"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Model Num"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_Quantity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Quantity"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_PPP"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Price per Pice"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autocomplitecn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Country "
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">




                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autocomplitecolor_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Color "
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_ProductSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Size"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/autocompliteDname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Dealer Name"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <EditText

                    android:id="@+id/edittext_Delleremail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Dealer Email"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_DellerPhn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Dealer Phn Num"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_Delleradd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Dealer Add"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp">


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittext_Dellerfax"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Dealer Fax"
                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />


            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

i add this code to my manifest file but no solution found

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.oggy.productcatalog.AddProductActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with layout not adjusting

```html
    <activity android:name="com.example.oggy.productcatalog.AddProductActivity" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" />
```

Comment: if i only use adjustnothing keyboard hide my bottom edit text field and also i can't scroll up or down

Comment: try with  android:fillViewport="true" in ScrollView

Comment: try with removing isScrollContainer or set it to false android:isScrollContainer="false"

Comment: its working with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"

Comment: bro i appreciate ur effort but bro still not working i try  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" but same result

Comment: I don't know what the problem then working fine on my emulator. following are setting  android:isScrollContainer="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" . good luck.

Comment: if that does not help keep tweaking you will find solution by yourself ;)

Comment: can u send me ur project if i provide u my email??

Comment: my email is mahadihasan1400@gmail.com